# Java jits method called in loop, performance improves drastically few runs later

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I was looking at HDFS and noticed that it spends a nontrivial amount of time verifying checksums, and after a few times it speeds up drastically.
I'm reading a 1 MB file, and it does a crc32c checksum 17 times because the file gets broken up into 64 KB packets.
Here's an example of the times, in seconds (the last packet is ~16KB):

```
0.005154
0.005455
0.005836
0.005837
0.005884
0.001014
0.000741
0.000756
0.000718
0.000712
0.000709
0.000712
0.000718
0.000678
0.000677
0.000700
0.000186
```

I ran java with `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation` and saw that it was jit-ing [org.apache.hadoop.util.PureJavaCrc32C#update](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/PureJavaCrc32C.java#L57) usually before the second verify checksum call.
However, it still takes ~5ms until the 6th call, when the time starts to plummet.

I made a separate Java file to test this, generating 65536 bytes of random data and computing its checksum 17 times (and each time I do the checksum on 512 byte chunks, just mimicking HDFS's behaviour).
I just copied the source for Hadoop's PureJavaCrc32C (linked above).
Here's the file http://ideone.com/aY1srS

On my computer, I see similar results as before (and if I run with `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation`, `PureJavaCrc32C#update` gets jit-ed before the second call as on HDFS)

```
0.010146
0.010859
0.012253
0.006862
0.000237
0.000225
0.000243
0.000244
0.000225
0.000242
0.000241
0.000243
0.000241
0.000241
0.000240
0.000239
0.000241
```

On ideone.com, the time actually drops immediately after the first call (maybe it uses more aggressive compilation/execution options?), though if I run on tutorialspoint.com I see a similar pattern of ~5 milliseconds-runs and then the rest sub-millisecond runs

I don't see anything new if I add `-XX:+PrintInlining`.
I also noticed it seems there's a run "in between" the first few slow times, and the rest "fast" times; in the first set of numbers, it drops from `~5ms -> ~1ms -> ~0.7ms`, in the test file on my computer it goes from `~10ms -> ~7ms -> ~0.2ms`, and on tutorialspoint it goes from `~4ms -> ~1.5ms -> ~0.1ms`

---

Can anyone explain this behaviour?
It doesn't seem like the JIT is obviously related to large the increase in performance midway through the loop, though other factors may be at play.
I don't know the details of how the JIT works, and couldn't find many good articles/papers explaining it, but I thought maybe after the JIT has compiled the function, it takes a while for the application thread to see and use the native function?
Also, if anyone could point to some good, in-depth JIT papers, that would be appreciated too

Comment: *It doesn't seem like the JIT is obviously related to large the increase in performance midway through the loop* JIT is related to this. It's its work.

Comment: I said "obviously related"; I'm sure it's related, but I don't understand it, and am asking for better insight

Comment: Part of why the JIT is so mysterious is...kind of deliberate: it's unspecified, frequently changes, and any docs would likely become swiftly out of date.  It's more or less magic.

Comment: The best document on how the JIT works is the OpenJDK source.

Comment: *"Other factors"* include the version of Java and OS, number of CPU cores, amount of system memory etc. As you've already noticed the behavior highly varies depending on the system. We can't tell without knowing the particular environment. E.g. Tiered compilation, number of compiler threads, CPU speed - all these affect JIT timings. Keep in mind that JIT may work in background, may run at different levels of optimization and may invalidate and recompile methods compiled earlier.

Comment: Another thing is: does it even matter? If you're only doing 17 loop iterations then the loop itself isn't hot code (its callees might be). If it's called often you probably want to care about steady-state, not about the first few iterations. If it's not called often, why care about a few milliseconds?